# Install vagrant plugin from source other than rubygems

Tags: rubygems, vagrant

We have an internal rubygems repository that we want to use to host Vagrant plugins. But, I cannot figure out how to tell 'vagrant plugin install' to use my repository instead of rubygems.org.

Answer (score 0):

I missed the documented `--plugin-source` option for `vagrant plugin install`.